# NodeJs terminates after redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js

My NodeJs server terminates after the code below

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
const name = req.body.name;
const email = req.body.email;
const message = req.body.message;
const sub = req.body.sub;
var d = 0;
if (sub == "on") {
    d = 1;
}

var sql = require('mssql');
var parameters = [
    { name: 'E_Id', sqltype: sql.VarChar, value: "24243" },
    { name: 'E_Name', sqltype: sql.VarChar, value: name },
    { name: 'E_Email', sqltype: sql.VarChar, value: email },
    { name: 'E_Message', sqltype: sql.VarChar, value: message},
    { name: 'E_IsSubscribe', sqltype: sql.Int, value: d },
];

var query = "INSERT INTO [E_Email] (E_Id, E_Name, E_Email, E_Message, E_IsSubscribe) VALUES (@E_Id, @E_Name, @E_Email, @E_Message, @E_IsSubscribe)";
executeQuery(res, query, parameters);

res.redirect("back");
});
```

and here where it terminates:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

    res.render("index"); // <-Terminates
    res.end();

 });
```

The index page has some fields and when i hit signup button the nodeJS server kills itself. The page should post back to its index

can anyone help me solve this.

Comment: Does it throw an error?

Comment: im not sure because the terminal just kills itself, so i cant see the error in the terminal

Comment: What does a post endpoint have to do with a get endpoint? Can you run this code locally and see?

Comment: i just want the index to post back to its same page once data is submitted on the form

Comment: so when the data is posted i do a get to get the index page again

Comment: im new to nodejs so trying to learn as i go

Comment: If you want to be on the same page after handling the post, then just render the page again at the end of the route.  There's no need for a redirect if you just want to render the same page again.  What doesn't make sense here is you say the `res.render("index")` causes nodejs to terminate.  If that's the case, then how did you get the page displayed the first time (before the POST)?

Comment: If `res.render("index")` causes things to fail, then I'd suggest you check on your template engine installation to see if everything there is configured correctly.  `res.render()` is for rendering templates when you have a view engine configured in Express.  If you just want to send a static HTML file, then just use `res.sendFile("index.html")` (use a path to the appropriate file).

Comment: i tried res.render but still terminates and sendfile its not html its .pub file

Comment: after i hit send it renders the index page with the fields empty but terminates nodejs